# Dojo - how to I programatically modify dojo-props?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.mobile

I have a ToolBarButton like such:

```
<span data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ToolBarButton" 
      data-dojo-props="label:'Back', moveTo:'config'" ></span>
```

You can see that I have the moveTo property declared as 'config' but how can I programatically change that?

I want to reuse this button but I want to call a function which will modify the value of moveTo.

Kinda like this:

```
<span data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ToolBarButton" onclick="modifyMoveTo('somePath')"
      data-dojo-props="label:'Back', moveTo:'config'" ></span>
```

Answer (score 3):

Is this part of a template? If so, you can give it an attach-point like

```
<span data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ToolBarButton" 
    data-dojo-attach-point="myButton" 
    data-dojo-props="label:'Back', moveTo:'config'" ></span>
```

and then change it by doing this:

```
this.myButton.set("moveTo", "somePath");
```

If not, you can give it an id, say 'myButton', and from your code, use the dojo's registry utility (dijit/registry), and do something like this:

```
var btn = registry.byId("myButton"); //This will return the widget
btn.set("moveTo", "somePath");
```

Answer (score 1):

The `data-dojo-props` are just a way to set properties using markup. If you look at the API docs for a [dojox/mobile/ToolbarButton](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.10/dojox/mobile/ToolBarButton) for example
, you'll see a lot of properties.

Also, if you look at the method summary you will see the following method:

> set(name,value) Set a property on a widget

So yeah, each widget has this method, allowing you to set any property that you can find in the API docs. For example:

```
myToolbarBtn.set('label', 'Back 2');
```

Now, to get a reference to the widget you want to change (for example `myToolbarBtn`), you can use the [`dijit/registry`](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/registry.html) module, which allows you to obtain the widgets by DOM node, ID, parent nodes, ... .

If you're using global functions like `modifyMoveTo()`, then you could obtain the `event.target` property to retrieve the DOM node, and then use:

```
require(["dijit/registry"], function(registry) {
    var myToolbatBtn = registry.byNode(evt.target);
});
```

And then you have access to the widget programmatically. Or like Richard said, you can use IDs, templates, ... .